# Change Buttons state in a Listview if a Button is clicked

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

I have a `list view` of buttons in which every row has play button. If i clicked on First Play Button it changes to pause but if i pressed second row play button,then first will remain in pause state but i want that if any of button is pressed then the previous back to its play satate button and the clicked one changes to pause. Please Help

```
      if (position == mPlayingPosition&&equals(subscription_type_user)) {

                        textview_duration_Current.post(mUpdateTime);
                        //pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Log.d("helyaa", String.valueOf(position));

                        mProgressUpdater.mBarToUpdate = pb;
                        mHandler.postDelayed(mProgressUpdater, 100);
                    } else {
                        Log.d("helnaa", String.valueOf(position));

                        //pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        pb.setProgress(0);
                        textview_duration_Current.setText("");
                        if (mProgressUpdater.mBarToUpdate == pb) {
                            //this progress would be updated, but this is the wrong position

                            mProgressUpdater.mBarToUpdate = null;
                        }
```

My List Click Event

```
      mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View item,
                                int position, long id) {
            Planet planet = listAdapter.getItem(position);
            planet.toggleChecked();
            PlanetViewHolder viewHolder = (PlanetViewHolder) item.getTag();
            //  viewHolder.getCheckBox().setChecked( planet.isChecked() );


            if (planet.isChecked()) {
                Toast.makeText(Main_New.this, "Play", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //start playing item at position
                try {
                    mPlayer.reset();
                    mPlayer.setDataSource(String.valueOf(planet = listAdapter.getItem(position)));

                    mPlayer.prepare();
                    mPlayer.start();
                    //mPlayingPosition = position;
                    Log.d("OnlyPos", String.valueOf(position));



                    // Log.d("Postionof", String.valueOf(mPlayingPosition));

                    //Toast.makeText(this,"Position of"+mPlayingPosition,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    // Updating progress bar
                    //updateProgressBar();

                    //trigger list refresh, this will make progressbar start updating if visible

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // Log.e( "unable to play: " + planetList.get(position));
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
            ;

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

1. keep a global int  variable called position
2. in your listView's `getView()` method check the position

   ```
   if (position == selectedPosition) {
   // change the button color or whatever 

               } else {
                 // keep things in the normal way
                   }
   ```
3. in your list view `setOnItemClickListener` update that variable position; and do a `notifyDataSetChanged()` to call the `getView` method

Done!

Comment: and i have lisview in main class!!

Comment: doesn't matter where it is you can use the logic

Answer (score 1):

set the listView parent radioGroup and set radioButton with custom drawable images of play/pause like that:-
drawable_state.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pause"  android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pause" android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/play" android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/play" android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="false"/>
</selector>
```

set this style attribute in radioButton tag

```
<style name="radionbutton"
        parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
        <item name="android:button">@drawable/drawable_state</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
```

this will solve your problam